# Speed-up increase of quickSort using OpenMP

Tags: c, performance, parallel-processing, openmp, quicksort

I've implemented the quicksort algorithm using the following C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <time.h>

int partition(int v[], int esq, int dir){
    int i, pos=esq,tmp; 
    //#pragma omp parallel for schedule(guided) 
    for(i=esq+1; i<=dir; i++){
        if(v[i]<v[esq]){
            pos++;
            tmp=v[i];
            v[i]=v[pos];
            v[pos]=tmp;
        }
    }
    //swap
    tmp=v[esq];
    v[esq]=v[pos];
    v[pos]=tmp;
    return pos;
}

void quickSort(int v[], int esq, int dir){
    int pos;
    if(esq<dir){
        pos=partition(v,esq,dir);
        //#pragma omp task
        quickSort(v,esq,pos-1);
        //#pragma omp task
        quickSort(v,pos+1,dir);
        //#pragma omp taskwait
    }
}

int main(){
    int N,i;
    scanf("%d",&N); //number of elements
    int v[N];
    for(i=0;i<N;i++) v[i]=rand() % 5000; //generate an array of random     numbers 
    double time=omp_get_wtime();
    //#pragma omp parallel  
    //#pragma omp single
    quickSort(v,0,N-1);
    double total=omp_get_wtime()-time;
    printf("Time \t %.8f",total);
    return 0;
}
```

To parallelize the code I've used the commented lines, but the problem is that, instead of a decrease in the execution time, I've got a  increase (speed-up inferior to 1).

I need some help to parallelize this code using OpenMP in a way that the execution time decreases.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you compiling with -fopenmp flag?

Comment: to compile I'm using
    gcc -O3 -fopenmp <file.c>

Comment: You may add an if clause so that parallel is invoked only  when  the swap segment is long enough that parallel is faster than simd. I guess your gcc may  not  observe parallel for simd .  As you might need multiple memory controllers to see potential for parallel speedup, you may have numa locality trouble.

Comment: If you are reinventing wheels by ignoring research on parallel sort you might be wasting time.

Comment: Which version of gcc are u using ?

Comment: The version I'm using is 4.8.4

Comment: tmp must be declared inside the parallel so that it will be private. Use of pos seems wrong, not only because you have all threads incrementing and sharing same value.

Comment: So, I should use #pragma omp parallel firstprivate(pos) ?